# Configure sendmail to send email for a specific user through another server?

Tags: sendmail

When a local user sends email via our sendmail, I want to have all his email forwarded through one another web server that I have control over.

I need this temporary fix, because he's off site, and has a lot of devices.  He can't easily change his outgoing server at the present time.

Thanks.